# Map CorefChain to CoreEntityMention in Stanford Core NLP

Tags: stanford-nlp

I want to construct a lookup map with the type `Map<CorefChain, CoreEntityMention>` using

```
Map<Integer, Integer> mapping = document.annotation().get(CoreAnnotations.CorefMentionToEntityMentionMappingAnnotation.class);
```

where `document` is a `CoreDocument`.

I have tried to get a set of CorefChains and a list of CoreEntityMentions to build such a map, but the indices do not seem to match up.

```
Map<Integer, CorefChain> chains = document.corefChains();
List<CoreEntityMention> entities = document.entityMentions();
```

---

Example:

Sentence:

```
 "ʿAmrān is a small city in western central Yemen. It is the capital of the 'Amran 
  Governorate, and was formerly in the Sana'a Governorate. It is located 52.9 
  kilometres by road northwest of the Yemeni capital of Sana'a. According to the 
  2004 census it had a population of 76,863, and an estimated population of 
  90,792 in 2012."
```

chains:

```
{
    1=CHAIN1-["a small city in western central Yemen" in sentence 1, "It" in sentence 2, "It" in sentence 3], 
    2=CHAIN2-["western central Yemen" in sentence 1], 
    4=CHAIN4-["the capital of the ` Amran Governorate" in sentence 2], 
    5=CHAIN5-["the ` Amran Governorate" in sentence 2], 
    6=CHAIN6-["the Sana'a Governorate" in sentence 2, "Sana'a" in sentence 3], 
    7=CHAIN7-["52.9" in sentence 3], 
    10=CHAIN10-["52.9 kilometres" in sentence 3], 
    11=CHAIN11-["road northwest of the Yemeni capital of Sana'a" in sentence 3], 
    12=CHAIN12-["the Yemeni capital of Sana'a" in sentence 3], 13=CHAIN13-["76,863" in sentence 4], 
    14=CHAIN14-["90,792" in sentence 4], 15=CHAIN15-["the 2004 census" in sentence 4, "it" in sentence 4], 
    17=CHAIN17-["a population of 76,863 , and an estimated population of 90,792 in 2012" in sentence 4], 
    18=CHAIN18-["a population of 76,863" in sentence 4], 
    19=CHAIN19-["an estimated population of 90,792 in 2012" in sentence 4], 
    20=CHAIN20-["2012" in sentence 4]
}
```

entities:

```
[Yemen, Sana'a Governorate, 52.9, Yemeni, Sana'a, 2004, 76,863, 90,792, 2012]
```

mapping:

```
{16=8, 7=2, 8=4, 13=5, 14=6, 15=7}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear, there are two types of mentions:

```
coref mentions
entity mentions
```

All `entity mentions` should be `coref mentions`, but not all `coref mentions` are `entity mentions`.

As you found there is a map from `coref mentions` to `entity mentions`.

You should be able to see the chain id with the `corefClusterID` property of the coref mention.  So you have a map of `coref mention` to `entity mention`, and you can convert the `coref mention` to the chain id by accessing the `corefClusterID` of the coref mention.